# iTunes connect renewal will not allow iAd contract to complete because of a banking page bug!

Tags: app-store-connect

So we've renewed our iTunes connect developer acccount. Now it says that all our APPS are on hold until we complete the iAd contract. So I try to do the bank bit (note that all our details have ALREADY been submitted) and I can't save to complete this step. It says you must change somthing. But I DO NOT WANT TO CHANGE THE BANK DETAILS. In the meantime, we are not selling APPs. What do we do!?

Answer (score 1):

For a problem with accounting forms and it's not clear to you whether submitting paperwork would delay sales of your app, I would call Developer Support directly:

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Choose the **Enrollment and Account** link and sign in to get your options.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be able to make some progress, by adding another bank account.
Presumably you can then switch back to the original bank account.